# Is there a procedure for flagging suspicious edits?

Tags: support

I was looking at the change history for the following question:

[Whats a good bike for under $450](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/35857/4808)

and  it looks to me as though the question morphed somewhat from the original post of

> Whats a good bike for under $450 that will help a 17 year old get from
>   place to place

to the final

> Looking for a bike for a 17 year old to get from place to place. On a
>   budget of $450 USD. What style of bike and how do I find the best
>   deals?

Now, this particular question doesn't really matter, since it has now been closed. But I was just wondering what the procedure is for flagging that an edit has changed the meaning of a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a formal procedure for that particular issue, but you could just use the normal "flag" link, and then select:

**In need of moderator intervention**
*A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!*

When you do that you are presented a text area in which to detail your concern with the question or the edit.

Comment: thanks Gary I hadn't realised there was a text box